# Array of dates is empty when trying to access it from picker options

Tags: typescript, vue.js, element-ui

I have an array of dates which are populated from the server which defines the dates to be disabled on the datepicker

```
 getStaffAvailability(){
            let x = this;
            this.$http.get(this.weeklyAvailabilityUrl + "GetAvailableDaysForStaff/" + this.entity.staffId)
                .then(function (event: any) {
                    x.staffAvailableDays = event.body;
                });
        }
```

after this method runs i can clearly see on the vue dev tools that this array is populated with the values as expected...
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cUpx.png

however on the datepicker option's disableddates method when i try to access the array it is empty and has no values in it. I don't understand why this is.

```
 export default class StaffAllocation extends Mixins<BaseCrudMixin>(BaseCrudMixin) {
        staffAvailableDays: Date[];
        datePickerOptions: any;

        @Prop(Number) eventId!: number;

        constructor() {
            this.staffAvailableDays = [];
            this.datePickerOptions = {
                disabledDate: (currentDate: Date) => {
                    return (this.staffAvailableDays.findIndex(item => { return item.getTime() == currentDate.getTime() })) == -1;
                }
            };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, `this.staffAvailableDays` is an array of `string` instead of a array of `Date`. It means `item.getTime()` will throw an exception.

What you can try is to parse the dates before assigning them:

```
getStaffAvailability(){
  let x = this;
  this.$http.get(this.weeklyAvailabilityUrl + "GetAvailableDaysForStaff/" + this.entity.staffId)
  .then(function (event: any) {
    x.staffAvailableDays = event.body.map(function (d) {
      return new Date(Date.parse(d));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried this, but the initial problem still is there that the array is empty when i try to access it in the disabledDate method

Comment: Did you check if the `disabledDate` function is called after the `staffAvailableDays` is set ? Did you ensure the array is really in `event.body` and not `event.body.staffAvailableDays` for example ? And is the `getStaffAvailability` method part of the `StaffAllocation` class (to be sure `this` refers to the proper instance of StaffAllocation) ?

Comment: Yes i checked all these things and problem still persists